# Desktop files moved to secondary monitor

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments

when I hook up a secondary monitor (to give a presentation or something) all my desktop files are placed on the secondary monitor. I want them to remain on my laptop desktop, which is emptied when I connect the secondary monitor. The laptopscreen (LVDS1) is already assigned as primary, and the taskbar is located on the laptopscreen. It's just the desktop files that are located on the secondary monitor (VGA1),I would really like to change this. I use 12.10. Any tips?

Cheers